# Finding relationship between two numbers directly that were changed cumulatively

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Bear with me. I'm not sure how to express this question let alone answer it.  Here goes...

I have a program that can calculate change from a single rate, we'll call 'A'.

Known: 
$$C = A + 400$$
$$B = C / 1.1$$
And therefore, $A =  1.1B - 400$.

However, my program would calculate 'B' as follows: 
$B = A/1.1 + 400$, whereas this should be $B = (A + 400)/1.1$

Example:
$A = 2075$, therefore:
$C = 2075 + 400 = 2475$
Correct --> $B = 2475 / 1.1 = 2250 $ 
How my program calculates --> $B = 2075 / 1.1 + 400$

Is there a way to around this, a way to calculate B from A?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  You ask if there is a way to calculate $B$ from $A$, but you show how to do that.  Are you trying to find out how to calculate an $A'$ from $A$, such that when the program is supplied the $A'$ instead of $A$ it gets the correct value of $B$ that the correct equation would give from $A$?  That can be done with algebra.  Often writing the question clearly will point the way to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say your program is wrong.  You are getting $B=A/1.1+400=A/1.1+4000/10$ when it should be $B=(A+400)/1.1=A/1.1+4000/11$  One approach is to take the $B$ that you get and subtract  $4000/10 - 4000/11 \approx 36.3636$

Comment: Yes! this is what I am looking for.  So, if 400 changes, The formula would be; y = (x/10) - (x/11). Assuming x = 400 and y = number I need to subtract from B.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need 
to completely parenthesize
your expressions.

Which language are you using,
and what is the actual code?

Comment: No Code.  I am the end user of the program.  I need to enter a 'base' number into the system 'A'.  And then provide a numerical or percentage change to the base to get 'B' and 'C'.

Comment: In other words, I can't change how the calculations are made.  I need to figure out a way around the program limitations to get the number I want.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: You've lost me.  The documentation on the the program is a book.  The program is basically a database for queries.  One should be able to ask for A, B, or C and get the numbers that I have; A=2075, B=2250, and C=2475.  However, because of how the program calculates B, I don't know how to get B to show as I have it; (2075 + 400)/1.1 = 2250.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not explaining this all too well.  For this program, I can enter 'A' and I can enter a change to A to get different numbers.  In this instance I want a number 'C' that is 400 more than 'A'.  And I want a number 'B' which is 10% less than C.  However the program calculates from A only.  So I can enter 'A' as 2075 and C as A+400.  But I'm not sure what I can enter to get B.

Comment: File in a bug complaint or change software,this is the best sollution